# iOS: Send multiple actions to a bar button

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

In my app I'm looking to customise a bar button that currently shows the user's location so that if the user taps and holds down it shows a subview with some other info. However it seems I can only send one action. Is this definitely the case or is there a way I can have more than one action? I know there's a subclass to enable the user orientation position (like in the Maps app) - could I somehow implement similar functionality?

Comment: you want touchup inside to do one thing, and touchdown to do something else?

Comment: That's what I thought but there's no option for that, at least in the connections inspector. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what you mean by "Sending an action" ? Do you want to trigger two actions when the button is pressed or do you want to capture two different events like "touch-up-inside" and "long-press" ?

Comment: The latter. I'd like it so if I tap it once it calls one method but if I tap and hold it calls another.

Comment: unfortunately, its not possible to do it with the native barbuttonItem. 

UIBarButtonItem inherits from the NSObject, and neither class has the addTarget method (required to do what you want), which is found in UIControl and its derived classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIBarButtonItems only send one event.  You'll need to create your own custom control, add Gesture Recognizers to it to recognize tap and long press, and create a bar button item with your custom control.

Answer (score 6):

Create your own `UIButton` and add all the gesture recognizers or actions you want. Then create the `UIBarButtonItem` with `initWithCustomView:`.

```
UIButton *btn = // create button as needed
btn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES; // keep the "glow" effect
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(someSelector) forControlEvents:someEvent];
// repeat as needed for different events/selectors
// or add gesture recognizers

UIBarButtonItem *btnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other comments say: It is not possible to add a "Long Press" gesture recognizer to the native bar button. There are two ways you could go about this:

1) Find the UIView that represents the button in the view hierarchy and add a gesture recognizer to it. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471390/using-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-and-uibarbuttonitem). This is is pretty straight forward and done with a few lines of code but might break in case internal structuring of the views change in the future.

2) Set a customView for the navigation bar button by dragging a UIButton onto it (Interfacebuilder) or setting the customView property programmatically. You then need to give that UIButton the appearance of a navBarButton and add a gesture recognizer to it.